# How do I inform a Json schema that it must have atleast one type of object in its Array, but other types are optional

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am working on updating a JSON schema for work.

For the json array, we have

```
"accountsInfo": [{
    "type":"ADMIN",
    "firstName":"Bill",
    "lastName":"Cipher",
    "emailAddress":"bcipher@gfalls.com"

}, {
    "type":"USER"
    "firstName":"Bugs",
    "lastName":"Bunny",
    "emailAddress":"whats@updoc.org"
}]
```

The USER type is needs to be optional for this schema, with the atleast 1 ADMIN type is required in the array. How can I do this?

Here is the portion of the schema file. It is using Json Schema 7.

```
  "accountsInfo": {
    "type": "array",
    "uniqueItems": true,
    "minItems": 2,
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "type",
          "firstName",
          "lastName",
          "emailAddress"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "ADMIN",
              "USER"
            ]
          },
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/non-empty-string"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/non-empty-string"
          },
          "emailAddress": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "email"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "contains" keyword for this. In pseudocode: "the array must contain (at least one) item that successfully evaluates against this schema".

As a sibling keyword to `"type": "object"` and `"items": { ... }`, add:

```
"contains": {
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "const": "ADMIN"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you have an error in your `"items"` keyword: if you intend for that subschema to match *all* items, not just the first, remove the extra array around the schema. The array form of "items" matches each item in the data against each item in the schema in turn, and you only specify a schema for the first item, so all items after the first can be anything.

`"items": { .. schema .. }` not `"items": [ { .. schema .. } ]`.

Answer (score 0):

If using the contains keyword as suggested, and if you are using strict mode, you may need to add "type": "array" like this:

```
  {
    "type": "array",
    "contains": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "ADMIN"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```